# PHPMailer sending to blank page

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to get PHPMailer to work to send mail from form data(obviously).

ISSUE:

When submitting form, I am getting sent to a blank page. No errors are being reported. I have followed as many stackoverflow threads surrounding this issue as I could find, and no solutions  in those threads resolved the issue for myself.

Thanks

ERRORS:

Fixed all errors aside from: 2016-03-26 22:10:43    SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2016-03-26 22:10:43   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

PHP:

```
<?php
$message=
'First Name:    '.$_POST['first'].'<br />
Last Name:  '.$_POST['last'].'<br />
Phone:  '.$_POST['phone'].'<br />
Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
Message:    '.$_POST['message'].'
';

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;           // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 587;

    // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = "xxxx@gmail.com"; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = "xxxx"; // Your Gmail password

    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname']);
    $mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    // Send To  
    $mail->AddAddress("xxxx@gmail.com", "xxxx"); // Where to send it - Recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();        // Send!  
    $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';      
    unset($mail);
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
 <form class="form-inline" name="contactform" action="mailer.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group form-sty">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="first" required>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control-sty" name="first" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group form-sty">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="last" required>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control-sty" name="last" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group form-sty">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="phone" required>Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control-sty" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group form-sty">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="email" required>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control-sty" name="mailfrom" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 form-sty">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="comment">Comment</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control-sty" name="message" id="message" rows="7" placeholder="What's on your mind?" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 form-sty form-sty-btn">
                        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default col-sm-12">Send</button>
                    </div>
                    <p><?php if(!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></p>
                </form>
```

Comment: You say that you have an issue and then don't say what the issue *is*.  What errors/warnings are you getting?  How can we help you if you just post a wall of badly formatted code?

Comment: Please dispense with the pleas and editorial. Just add the relevant code and clearly state the problem.

Comment: Sorry, It's in the title. Issue is, PHPMailer is sending me to a blank page after submitting. 

I'm not getting any errors, it just goes to the blank page.

Comment: I assume you've tried Port 465 with SSL?  Pretty sure that is what Google uses.  9/10 these problems are incorrect server information.  Seems odd that you aren't getting any output at all.  Try adding `echo` statements to debug.

Comment: Yes sir, I have tried both TLS and SSL ports with no success.

Comment: Sorry if what I posted didn't make sense. I felt if I didn't add the editorial it may be flagged as a repeat issue when I have read all threads relating to this reported issue on Stackoverflow and no solution in those threads has resolved mine. Moving forward, I will do a better job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the header back to the form (I assume that is where you want to send them) Replace the location inside the header with your URL

```
<?php
$message=
'First Name:    '.$_POST['first'].'<br />
Last Name:  '.$_POST['last'].'<br />
Phone:  '.$_POST['phone'].'<br />
Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
Message:    '.$_POST['message'].'
';

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;           // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 587;

    // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = "xxxx@gmail.com"; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = "xxxx"; // Your Gmail password

    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname']);
    $mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    // Send To  
    $mail->AddAddress("xxxx@gmail.com", "xxxx"); // Where to send it - Recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();        // Send!  
    if ($result)
    {
        header("Location: : http://www.example.com/contactform.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "sending mail failed: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    unset($mail);
}
?>
```

Comment: This is actually giving me the following error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xxxx/public_html/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php:234) in /home/xxxx/public_html/mailer.php on line 41

Comment: You cannot echo any output before setting a header. So make sure there are no debug echos before the header.

Comment: Resolved this as well. I had to disable/comment out the SMTPDebug and it worked just fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should consider filtering your inputs and adding some spam filtering techniques. May be a question for another topic but you could start with http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure there are no errors. Try placing this code at the top of your file to make sure all errors/warnings are reported and run the script again.

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: thank you, I'm able to see errors now. Will post if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Alright I fixed all errors aside from: 2016-03-26 22:10:43 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2016-03-26 22:10:43 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Alright, figured that out too. Godaddy only allows the use of it's SMTP servers. So stupid.